# Problem with reading user data of an app developped with Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have been introduced to Firebase a few days ago. Since then I have been trying to discover more features and usage of Firebase, in particular, the usage of the Firestore/Realtime Database.

However, as I am reading into more details, I start to think of some questions. I hope someone that is familiar with Firebase can help me answer them

1. As for User authentication, I understand that I can use Firebase Authentication where I won't see their real password. However, technically, everything that user stores in my Firestore would be visible to me since I am the owner of the Firebase.

   - For example, if I were to develop a note/chat app, in which the user can access their notes/chat on the iOS app and also Android. That means all their notes data would be saved in my database. If it happens to contain some private data, then I would be able to read it?
   - Even if I set security rules, that would be only facing client-side, whereas, for me, the owner of the entire firebase data, I could see the whole thing. Surely, as a customer, you won't want to use an app knowing that I can see everything you write

I am not sure if what I said is true or not. If true, is there a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your statements are correct. This happens in most of the apps-websites, the admin or some core developers have full access to the data. That's why **privacy policy** and **GDPR** exist. You must specify what data you collect and for what reason. If you intend to use your user data for any other reason you must inform them. Be aware that if you disclose any user information without his permission you can be held liable.